Audio editor that allows modifying the raw samples
I have an audio file with a section that looks like this in Audacity at high zoom level:

and there is of course an audible click in the audio here. I believe I could mitigate it significantly if I could move just these few audio samples closer to the baseline, but I can't find a way to do it within Audacity. Is it possible? Is there some other software with which I can do it?

With the Draw tool, you can change an individual sample.
